# Indices/Exponents: Simplify the following expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I've been asked to simplify this expressing it with positive indices/exponents. Could someone please show me in steps how to do this? The answer is shown next to it. Thanks a lot.

$$\dfrac{{(\large a^\frac{-5}{2})}^2 b^2}{\large {a}^3(b^\frac{1}{4})^6} = \dfrac{b^\frac{1}{2}}{a^8}$$

Comment: Sorry. In Australia we call them indices :)

Comment: Huh, I've never heard that.  Here in the US "indices" usually refers to subscripts.

Comment: Indices is a British term, so it's used in the commonwealth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power of $a$ in the numerator = $\dfrac{-5}{2} \cdot 2 = -5$

Power of $a$ in the denominator = $3$

Overall power of $a$ in the final equation = $-5 - 3 = -8$

Power of $b$ in the numerator = $2$

Power of $b$ in the denominator = $\dfrac{1}{4} \cdot 6 = \dfrac{3}{2}$

Overall power of $b$ in the final equation = $2 - \dfrac{3}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2}$

Hence the answer is $a^{-8} \cdot b^{\frac{1}{2}} = \boxed{\dfrac{\large{b}^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\large{a}^8}}$

Answer (score 2):

$$ \begin{eqnarray*}  
\left(  a^{-\frac 52} \right)^2 = a^{-5}
\\ \frac 1{a^3}=a^{-3}
\\ \dfrac 1 { \left(  b^{\frac 14} \right)^6}=b^{-\frac 32}
\end{eqnarray*} $$

so

$$ \begin{eqnarray*}  
\dfrac {\left(  a^{-\frac 52} \right)^2b^2 }{a^3\left(  b^{\frac 14} \right)^6}
&=a^{-5}a^{-3}b^2 b^{-\frac 32}
\\&=a^{-8}b^\frac 12
\end{eqnarray*} $$